# Draw on screen using Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, directx, overlay

im working on a project that i use Node and i reached a point that i need to create an **overlay** to show some information over a program, anyone knows a way to do that using **Node**? I tried both a **Chromium** with an invisible background and [**EdgeJS**](https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge), but its not what im looking for, i searched some stuff on internet and i've found that most people do that (in **C++**) using **DirectX**, most off gamehacking stuff, but i didn't found anything related to that in javascript , anyone knows a way to use DirectX libs or to create an overlay using NodeJS only? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Node.js is usually used as a server backend and has no GUI at all, why do you want to use it on the client side to draw an overlay?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please provide the details on what have you tried so far?
Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) wherever required. Also please take the time to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: @xander im working on a gamehack using Node and i want to draw some simple [ESP boxes](https://i.imgur.com/gVGkbY6.jpg), im currently using [memoryjs](https://github.com/Rob--/memoryjs) and it works really well, and now i want to move to the drawning stuff

Comment: @pratibha Tnx for the "How to ask" , the only examples that i can provide now are in c++ like[this one](https://www.mpgh.net/forum/showthread.php?t=891301) from another forum

Answer (score 0):

Why are you not using the Canvas API or WebGL API? I am assuming that the information displayed will be viewed in the browser? I would stay clear of DirectX as this is a Microsoft, IE only solution, not a long term solution.

You can also run NodeJS environment in windows quite easily by using IIS and it's ARR as a reverse proxy.

http://www.pixijs.com/

http://fabricjs.com/

Comment: Actually i dont want to depend on a browser to show the information, its a simple js that gets info from the game and use it, i need a way to create an overlay that allows me to draw some simple stuff like lines and text

Comment: In that case look at some of the server side graphics applications, like [link](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) .Try and stay clear of ActiveX